# How to open containing folder of file in Sublime Text 3 in OSX?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

How can I open the containing folder of an open file in Sublime Text 3 in OSX?  Prefer an answer that shows me where the menu option is, rather than setting up a command-line.

Some other posts I've searched suggest right-clicking the file and selecting the Open Containing Folder option, but I don't see it on mine...

[image: Right click sidebar]

Comment: Isn't this question meant to be for Super user? This is not related to programming .

Answer (score 3):

What you read is correct, but you may be falling afoul of the fact that the context menu that you get when you right click on the file ***tab*** is different than the one that you get if you right click in the ***file itself*** and, counter-intuitively, the option for opening the containing folder (or copying the path of the file to the clipboard) only appears in the *file* context menu.

The option you want is `Reveal in Finder`, which is near the bottom of the menu (note that my menu may be slightly different than yours depending on installed packages):

[image: Reveal in Finder menu location]